# How to attest simultaneous knowledge of $2$ private keys?

Tags: rsa, elliptic-curves

I'm looking for a way for a *single individual* to sign or otherwise provide proof of ownership of two private keys from keypairs $A$ & $B$.

Simultaneous ownership is important. Alice can't do part of the proof with $A$, then pass the proof to Bob to finish with $B$. The proof requires both keys in a single step. E.g. Signing a message with $A$ then $B$ does not work, as this work could be split between two actors.

Both $A$ & $B$ keypairs are normal, independent keypairs. I.e. this isn't about splitting a single private key into multiple parts to be reconstructed.

Any hints are appreciated, though eventually I'd want to implement this using RSA or ECDSA.

Update: Some further boundaries:

- This doesn't have to be a single step, or a single signature. As long as it can't be colluded on by two parties without exposing their private keys, any process is acceptable.

Comment: I don't think you can. If Bob's going to assist Alice in attesting ownership of private keys A and B, then he could just give her his private key B, rendering moot any such attempt at proof.

Comment: The point is to ensure that if two people collude, they HAVE to share private keys. (Or at least, I want to ensure that there is no way that A + B could be proven together without one party knowing both keys). 

The intention is for a single party who owns two keys to prove ownership. Bob should not be involved, as he does not want to share his private key.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cheapest way to prove that two different private keys are known to the same person?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/96630/cheapest-way-to-prove-that-two-different-private-keys-are-known-to-the-same-pers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alice has the (private, public) EC key pair $(a, A=aG)$, and Bob has $(b, B=bG)$.

Let's say that Alice starts the signature, and gives it to Bob to complete (or somehow collaborates with Bob to complete it). This would mean that either:

1. You need to ensure that whatever Alice gives to Bob will reveal $a$ to Bob, with no possible way for any scheme to be devised that would prevent Bob from learning $a$ through some form of blinded collaboration.
2. The signature is not zero-knowledge, and will reveal one of the private keys to the holder of the other private key.

An easy way to achieve option 2 would be to provide a signature by either $A$ or $B$, and to include the value $d=a-b$. A verifier can easily check that $dG\overset{?}{=}A-B$. This means that knowledge of $d$ would allow someone with knowledge of either $a$ or $b$ to recover the value of $b$ or $a$ respectively.

Normally, Alice would not want anyone else to know $d$, as certain signature schemes that do not properly bind to the intended public key would be malleable by someone that wanted to make a signature signed by $A$ look like it was actually signed by $B$. But, this can be avoided as long as the signature scheme is secure against this attack, and this threat may not matter if it is public knowledge that $A$ and $B$ are owned by the same person.

Since this is not a zero-knowledge proof, there is the risk that knowledge of $d$ could have adverse consequences in certain scenarios that I have not imagined.

Comment: This is precisely the information I was looking for, thankyou for explaining some of the potential risks, I can proceed from here. 

"Proceed" does not mean put this in to practice ;) I'm aware the potential risk of malleability attack or another attack warrant a lot more work.

Comment: @AlexHeeton: If I understand correctly, $b-a\bmod n$ (where $n$ is the order of $G$) is made public. Importantly, that allows Alice to sign as Bob, and vice versa.

Comment: @fgrieu To rephrase your issue, you're saying that if `b-a mod n` is public, then the owner of `b` will know `a`? If so, that is desirable.

Answer (score 1):

One solution for the ECDSA case is to have the owner sign with the key a+b (that is adding the private keys together mod the order of the curve).

This is straightforward to verify since the public key is also A+B (that is adding the public keys together).

Comment: The obvious problem with [your proposed RSA solution](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/101686/2) is that the holders could generate the padded message $m$ (padded to the length of $n_1n_2$), and then they individually generate $m^{e^{-1}} \bmod n_1, m^{e^{-1}} \bmod n_2$, and then it's easy to combine those two signatures to form $m^{e^{-1}} \bmod n_1 n_2$, generating a signature where neither side knew both private keys.  I believe that a similar approach can be done with ECDSA; however it's a little trickier to do without an internal value leaking anything

Comment: As usual, I should not be writing things about RSA. I will have to think more about the ECDSA case.

Comment: Good idea, and thanks poncho for pointing out the weakness.

Comment: Addition: that ECDSA solution might translate to many signature systems where the private key is the discrete logarithm of the public key in some (fixed) public group, including [DSA](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A53%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C70%2C700%2C0%5D), [EdDSA](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8032), and [various Schnorr signatures](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/50202/555). [update] But I'm still wondering if B could post-process a signature made by A into one that verifies, without knowing A's private key…